# Rails ActiveRecord handle an id column that is not the primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, primary-key

Struggling with ActiveRecord auto assigning the :id attribute as the primary key even though it is a separate column.

```
Table - legacy-table

    id - int
    pk_id - int (primary key)
    name - varchar2
    info - varchar2
```

Model

```
class LegacyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'legacy-table'
  self.primary_key = 'pk_id'
  default_scope {order(:name => :asc)}
  alias_attribute :other_id, :id

end
```

I don't care that ActiveRecord automatically assigns the primary key (pk_id) to the :id attribute however I lose all access to the actual id column.  Trying to use the alias simply points me back at the primary key.

However one caveat to this issues is that from the view i can access the id column by using @legacymodel[:id].  But again when calling @legacymodel.id I get the value of the pk_id column.  What i want is to be able to call @legacymodel.other_id and have it point to the id column.  Instead @legacymodel.service_id, @legacymodel.id, and @legacymodel.pk_id all point to the same column pk_id

Please note that this is a legacy db and modifying the columns are out of the question.  I am using Rails 4 with MySql.

Is there anyway to code around this?  Why does @legacymodel[:id] give me different results then @legacymodel.id?

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @cschroed did not work for me in the latest Rails (v4.2). Digging into the Rails source code, it appears that `read_attribute` will also use the primary key value if the key passed equals 'id':

```
  ID = 'id'.freeze

  # Returns the value of the attribute identified by <tt>attr_name</tt> after
  # it has been typecast (for example, "2004-12-12" in a date column is cast
  # to a date object, like Date.new(2004, 12, 12)).
  def read_attribute(attr_name, &block)
    name = attr_name.to_s
    name = self.class.primary_key if name == ID
    _read_attribute(name, &block)
  end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb

Since, the [] method uses `read_attribute`, this no longer works.

I found that directly reading from the attributes hash worked instead:

```
# LegacyModel class
def other_id
  @attributes.fetch_value('id')
end
```

This provided a means of bypassing `read_attribute` by mimicking `_read_attribute`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`read_attribute` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb) will read a value out of the `@attributes` hash.  The [`[]` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb) uses `read_attribute`.  So `@legacymodel[:id]` gets the value of the `id` column.

The [`write_attribute` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb) always tries to translate `id` into the name of the primary key...

```
# ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write
def write_attribute(attr_name, value)
  attr_name = attr_name.to_s
  attr_name = self.class.primary_key if attr_name == 'id' && self.class.primary_key
```

...and the [`[]=` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb) uses `write_attribute`.  So `@legacymodel[:id] = <value>` will set a value into the primary key column, `pk_id`.

The [`id` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb) is a special method that is aliased to the `primary_key` here:

```
# ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::PrimaryKey
if attr_name == primary_key && attr_name != 'id'
  generated_attribute_methods.send(:alias_method, :id, primary_key)
end
```

So `@legacymodel.id` will get the value of the `pk_id` column.

If you just want to read the `id` column through `@legacymodel.other_id`, then you could define a method like:

```
# LegacyModel class
def other_id
  self[:id]
end
```

But if you also need to write to the `id` column through `@legacymodel.other_id=`, then you might need to try to find a safe way to override the `write_attribute` method so that you can work around the `attr_name = self.class.primary_key if attr_name == 'id' && self.class.primary_key` statement.

Comment: Agreed, is there any easy workaround to get passed the write_attribute logic?  Or is my only option to override ActiveRecord?

Comment: I can't think of a great way to get around this.  One option to consider would be to create a new method called `write_id_attribute` that is a copy of `write_attribute` without the `primary_key` logic.  Then in your model you could have `def other_id=(value) write_id_attribute(:id, value) end`.  This would make sure that the special logic would only ever be used for `id` in this one model and the standard `write_attribute` would still be used for everything else.

Comment: I had a similar issue so I tried adding a `write_id_attribute` method... it worked in principle but in the end I overrode the `write_attribute` method in a concern and only included that when required. Details in my related question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377791/7098196)