# ActiveRecord w/o Rails and existing ID column

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have an existing Sqlite table that's got an `id` column, but it's not the primary key. The primary key is named `ROWID`.

So in my model I've done:

```
  self.primary_key = "ROWID"
```

However, because the `id` field actually has good data in, AR is overwriting that data when it instantiates the records with the value from `ROWID`.

How do I go about preserving the value in the `id` column, while indicating `ROWID` is the primary key?

`[6] pry(main)> Message.first.handle
D, [2015-09-14T08:58:59.250979 #921] DEBUG -- :   Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "message".* FROM "message"  ORDER BY "message"."ROWID" ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2015-09-14T08:58:59.252343 #921] DEBUG -- :   Handle Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "handle".* FROM "handle" WHERE "handle"."ROWID" = ? LIMIT 1  [["ROWID", 8]]
=> #<Handle:0x007ff0f930c0e0 ROWID: 8, id: 8, country: "us", service: "iMessage", uncanonicalized_id: nil>`

[image]

Comment: what do you mean AR is overwriting the `id` column?

Comment: @engineersmnky Added more detail give more color

Comment: Okay I would try to explain but this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298349/rails-activerecord-handle-an-id-column-that-is-not-the-primary-key) has done a better job than I would have any way.

Comment: The suggested method of using `self[:id]` does not produce the correct result. It's still the overridden value.

Comment: Looks like going through `read_attribute` will still get changed: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb#L86. Using `_read_attribute` actually worked, but feels incredibly hacky.

Comment: I agree that it is a bit hacky but integrating legacy systems with ActiveRecord generally is. Glad you found a feasible solution to your issue.

Answer (score 3):

`_read_attribute(:id)` did the trick